# Find the value of $c$ which satisfies Rolle's Theorem for the function $f(x)=x^3-12x$ on the interval $[0,2\sqrt3]$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, rolles-theorem

> Find the value of $c$ which satisfies Rolle's Theorem for the function $f(x)=x^3-12x$ on the interval $[0,2\sqrt3]$.

[image: Link to Problem]

So I know that I have to take the derivative in problem 1, but after that I am clueless.

Comment: Answered down below, make sure you vote up and accept the answer if it's the one that fits you.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x) = x^3 - 12x$ satisfies the conditions for Rolle's theorem in $[0,2\sqrt{3}]$. That means that : $\exists x_0 \in [0,2\sqrt{3}] : f'(x_0) =0 \Leftrightarrow 3x^2 - 12 = 0 \Leftrightarrow x_0^2 = 4 \Leftrightarrow x_0=2 $ or $x_0=-2$. But you want $ x_0 \in [0,2\sqrt{3}]$ so that $x_0 = 2$.